# Inner constructor in Julia

Tags: object, struct, julia

I am moving from using Python to Julia and would like to create an object like this:

```
class myObject():
  def __init__(inputA,inputB):
    self.x = inputA;
    self.y = inputB;
    self.z = x*y;
```

I know that in Julia we use `struct` but am unsure how to implement the functionality as describe above without setting `z` manually (outside of the inner-constructor). How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it either as an inner constructor:

```
struct A
    x::Int
    y::Int
    z::Int
    # Inner constructor
    A(x, y) = new(x, y, x*y)
end
```

or an outer constructor:

```
struct B
    x::Int
    y::Int
    z::Int
end
# Outer constructor
B(x, y) = B(x, y, x*y)
```

Everything should be covered in the [Constructors section of the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/).

Comment: Hah so simple thank you. Would I be able to create constructors with different number of inputs?